# Algorithm to find minimal basis set of sets?

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose we have *N* sets { *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, *x*<sub>3</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*N*</sub> }.

A "basis" of these *N* sets is a collection of *M* sets { *y*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>, *y*<sub>3</sub>, …, *y*<sub>*M*</sub> } such that each of { *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, *x*<sub>3</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*N*</sub> } is the union of some combination of { *y*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>, *y*<sub>3</sub>, …, *y*<sub>*M*</sub> }.

How can I find a "minimal" basis, meaning a basis with the least possible *M*?

Comment: this would be better on http://math.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: Is it required that the yi are disjoint?

Comment: Seems similar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: And is it also be required that any union of subsets from the collection `{yi}` would necessarily be a member of the collection `{xi}`?

Answer (score 0):

One similar problem, that comes to mind, is finding the [basis of a vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29) or finding a minimal [generating set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set), respectively.

As the number of sets and thus the universe over all possible elements is a finite number, we could rewrite each set as a vector like this (assuming integer numbers as elements inside the sets):

```
{ 1, 2, 5 } => ( 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 , ... )
{ 4 }       => ( 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ... )
```

The set of all the vectors `x_i`s now form a (trivial) generating set `G` for the universe of all sets `x_i`.

You search for a minimal generator. To do so, we have to eliminate all linear dependencies from the vector set `G`. A naive approach would be to check all triples with elements of `G` for the following condition (`x,y,z` vectors of `G` and `k,l,m` numbers):

```
  k * x + l * y  + m * z == 0
```

If the condition is satisfied, we eliminate one vector of those three. (It does not really matter which one).

The such reduced set of vectors (and their respective sets) form a basis for you set of sets.

<sup>One requirement for the above argument is, that you allow for [set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement) as an operation to generate your sets.</sup>

Comment: Yes set difference I can allow.  That is okay if it makes problem easier.

Comment: do {0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1} form a vector space ?

Comment: @user1080552 That's a generating set, but not a minimal one. `1 * (0,1) + 1 * (1,0) == (1,1)` so at least one of those three should be dropped. `(0,0)` is the origin, which is part of any vector space, but is not part of the generating set (you can't create any other vector from it). So in the end just `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` could form your minimal generating set.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP-complete problem.

Comment: There are papers explaining that if you search for set basis problem.